# SwiftUI Keyboard shortcut doesn't work if Button has a buttonStyle

Tags: swift, swiftui

This works

```
Button(action: {
   print("pressed")
}){
   Text("Button")
}
.keyboardShortcut("B", modifiers: .command)
```

This doesn't

```
Button(action: {
   print("pressed")
}){
   Text("Button")
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
.keyboardShortcut("B", modifiers: .command)
```

Has anyone else experienced this

Comment: Did you try swapping the two modifiers, so that `.buttonStyle` is the second one?

Comment: Same problem with `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction)`...reversed too, still not working...
removing `buttonStyle` works fine...

Comment: Temporary ugly solution I adopted is to clone the button, remove content and apply `.opacity(0).frame(width: 0, height: 0).padding(0)` (`.isHidden` prevents `.keyboardShortcut` from activating), and have this hidden one respond to the key event

Comment: I can confirm that the `keyboardShortcut()` modifier still breaks in 2023 on Ventura when a `buttonStyle` is applied. @Giovazz89 solution of invisible unstyled buttons seems to be a good workaround, though. 
Please submit bug reports to Apple on https://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug. However, if you use a lowercase `"b"` it works as expected:

```
Button(action: {
    print("pressed")
}) {
    Text("Button")
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
.keyboardShortcut("b", modifiers: .command)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I am working on a conditional view, `.keyboardShortcut` does not work with `.buttonStyle(.plain)` for some reason. But if you try `.buttonStyle(.borderless)`, it will magically work. You can try out other styles to see which ones work.

```swift
Button(action: {
    print("pressed")
}) {
    Text("Button")
}
.buttonStyle(.borderless)
.keyboardShortcut("b", modifiers: .command)
```